# error in concatenation of two integers with string conversion

Tags: python

I have a list of these town IDs:

I need to generate a Unique ID for each observation (approximately 7000 in total) with the town ID being the first three digits of the Unique ID.

What I did:

```
ID = random.sample(range(1000,99000), 6970)

final['Unique ID'] = int(str(final['town_id'] + str(final['ID']))
```

Both the town_id and ID are integers.

I get an error like this:

[image]

Comment: **Both the town_id and ID are integers.** No, they aren't. At least one of them is multiple integers separated by newlines and spaces.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `ID` here. What is `final["ID"]`?

Comment: final is the name of my dataframe. ID represents the random numbers I generated in the first code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `str(final['ID'])`, you are essentially taking the entires series and converting that to a string. I guess what you would want is something like this:

```
final['Unique ID'] = int(final['town_id'].astype('str') + final['ID'].astype('str'))
```

Comment: I get a 'type error' which states that it cannot convert the series to type int

Comment: I guess you should create a minimal reproducible example as suggested. It would be easier to understand then. If your columns have purely numeric values, then converting to int as shown shouldn't be a problem. It seems that you have atleast one value which is not purely numeric.